# :before pseudo element is not working

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Following link is affected: https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=2753787&tc_deviceCategory=undefined&template_layout_id=5699672553&updated=1523614982274

We are experiencing problems with a form and its parent div. We tried to bring in a frosted glas style to the parent div landingboxForm, but if we are working with pseudoelements, nothing happens.

The tutorial is from here https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/how-to-do-css-only-frosted-glass-effect-e2666bafab91 and is working well for others. I just do not succeed in port it for our landing page.

Does anybody know why the :before div tag is just grey in the Chrome inspector and why it does not appear?

CSS:

```
   .lp-sorba {
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 900px !important;
}

.lp-sorba .landingpageHeader {
height: 80px;
background: #1d89d2;
}

.lp-sorba #hs-link-logo > img {
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.lp-sorba .landingboxForm:before {
 content:" ";
 background: inherit; 
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0; 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 filter: blur(10px) !important;
}

.lp-sorba .landingboxForm {
  background: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 23px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  border: 0.5px solid #edebeb;
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the piece of CSS you've got so far?

Without seeing it, maybe you are viewing it in a browser that doesn't support CSS filters?  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Thanks I added the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question

> why the :before div tag is just grey in the Chrome inspector and why it does not appear?

Your pseudo element is collapsing right know. Add `position: absolute;` to the `.lp-sorba .landingboxForm:before` rule.

---

But that won't solve your underlying problem / won't create the frosted glass effect.

The way how filters work is: they get applied to the element itself only, not the ones lying behind it.

In the example from Medium/Codepen, the form element inherits the background from the main element. By that it's pseudo element may apply a filter to it.

In your setup, the form is positioned absolute, while the image tag is also positioned absolute. The forms filter won't bleed into that image tag.

Revisit the example:

- apply a background image to a parent container
- inherit that in the form
- pseudo filter on the form will blur the forms inherited background